# Why text function of xpath doesn't show any data on scrapy selenium?

Tags: selenium, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a website with scrapy-selenium. **I am facing two problem**

1. I applied xpath on chrome developer tool I found all elements but after execution of code it returns only one Selector object.
2. text() function of xpath expression returns none.

This is the URL I am trying to scrape: http://www.atab.org.bd/Member/Dhaka_Zone

Here is a screenshot of inspector tool:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


class AtabDSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'atab_d'

    def start_requests(self):

        yield SeleniumRequest(
            url = "https://www.atab.org.bd/Member/Dhaka_Zone",
            #url = "https://www.bit2lead.com",
            #wait_time = 15,
            wait_time = 3,
            callback = self.parse
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        companies = response.xpath("//ul[@class='row']/li")
        print("Numbers Of Iterable Item: " + str(len(companies)))
        for company in companies:
            yield {
                "company": company.xpath(".//div[@class='card']/div[1]/div/a/h3[@data-bind='text: NameOfOrganization']/text()").get()
                #also tried
                #"company": company.xpath(".//div[@class='card']/div[1]/div/a/h3/text()").get()
            }
```

Here is a screenshot of my terminal:
[image]

And This is the url: ( https://www.algoslab.com ) I was practicing before That worked well. Although it's simple enough.

Comment: You should let the script wait until the content is loaded. [This is](https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium#wait_time--wait_until) how you can do that.

Comment: Are you sure there's a single space after the colon in "text: NameOfOrganization"?

Comment: @MichaelKay Yes there is a single space after the colon. Thank you for responding

Comment: @SIM I tried accordingly and it's same as before. I used id "DhakaZoneMemberListDiv". Would you please like to check again. Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try directly like the following to get everything in one go with the blink of an eye:

```
import requests

link = 'http://123.253.36.205:8051/API/Member/GetMembersList?searchString=&zone=0&blacklisted=false'

r = requests.get(link)
for item in r.json():
    _name = item['NameOfOrganization']
    phone = item['Phone']
    print(_name,phone)
```

Output are like (should produce 3160 lines of results):

```
Aqib Travels & Tours Ltd. +88-029101468, 58151369
4S Tours & Travels Ltd 8954750
5M Logistics And Tours Ltd +880 2 48810030
```

Comment: Well, That's helpful to get my job done thank you so much for that. But real problem is still under the shadow. I did not understand what's happening in your "link" variable. I need to know because there are more projects to complete that does not work similarly. If you help me solving my problem rather give me alternative solution I will be more than happy. Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

The xpath you want could be simplified as `//h3[@data-bind='text: NameOfOrganization']` to select the element and then view the text

Comment: Even more simplified `//h3[ends-with(@data-bind,'NameOfOrganization')]`. it also excludes the namespace.

Comment: @DMart Yes, But I didn't do that because you know the beginner's confusion. Anyways, that did not work either. I want to mention here that my code works in other website but not in this website. I used [scrapy proxy pool](https://github.com/rejoiceinhope/scrapy-proxy-pool) and [Scrapy user agents](https://pypi.org/project/scrapy-user-agents/)  too.